# How to combine CASE statement with Inner Join for Alphanumeric OrderBY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

In this query, I am trying to select all distinct (alphanumeric) machine names and order them correctly (1,2,5,10,15 instead of 1,10,15,2,5).  The CASE statement is proven to work when the LocalName is not joined by INNER JOIN, so I suspect this is where the problem lies.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MCGroup, VisionMachinePerformance.MCSAP, ZAssetRegister.LocalName 
FROM [VisionMachinePerformance] INNER JOIN ZAssetRegister ON VisionMachinePerformance.MCSAP=ZAssetRegister.SAP_Number 
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName) > 1 THEN 
LEFT(LocalName,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName)-1) 
ELSE LocalName END , 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName) > 1 THEN 
CAST(SUBSTRING(LocalName,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName),LEN(LocalName)) as float) 
ELSE NULL END
```

The error that is reported is "SQL Error (145): ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified".

I have tried changing all references in the CASE statement to ZAssetRegister.LocalName and VisionMachinePerformance.LocalName without success.

Removing all of the CASE statement and ordering by LocalName does work, but with the wrong order as mentioned above (1,10,15,2,5).

Could anybody suggest how to make this work?

TIA!

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; you need to include the expression(s) in your `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT`, or not use `DISTINCT`. Alternativelyyou could move the `SELECT` into a CTE`, and then do the `ORDER BY` on the data returned from the CTE.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu I dont follow, could you please elaborate?  I just tried copying the CASE statement into the SELECT but that didnt work.  I need the DISTINCT in this case, as I am building a unique list of Machines that I will later perform individual queries on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate both parts using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MCGroup, VisionMachinePerformance.MCSAP, ZAssetRegister.LocalName 
    FROM [VisionMachinePerformance]
    INNER JOIN ZAssetRegister ON VisionMachinePerformance.MCSAP=ZAssetRegister.SAP_Number
) DISTINCT_DATA
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName) > 1
         THEN LEFT(LocalName,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName)-1) 
         ELSE LocalName END,
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName) > 1
         THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(LocalName,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LocalName),LEN(LocalName)) as float)
         ELSE NULL END
```